# Pandas unable to assign value to cell

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a value to the Team Name value in the df, I was able to retrieve the value at the cell but when i tried to assign a value to it, it wont reflect the change

```
Unnamed: 0    Name    Email              Roll Number    Phone Number    Discord Id    Team Name
0        0    Name    email@google.edu    1025            9821090000    discordid#4431    NaN
```

`register[register['Discord Id'] == 'discordid#4431']['Team Name']`

gives the output

```
0   NaN 
Name: Team Name, dtype: float64
```

`register[register['Discord Id'] == 'discordid#4431']['Team Name'] = 'Team1'` does not reflect any changes
in the dataframe
can anybody help?

Comment: Use .loc and don't chain index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
mask = register['Discord Id'] == 'discordid#4431'
register.loc[mask, 'Team Name'] = 'Team1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
df['Team Name'] = df['Discord ID']
```